# Does Pine Script have a substitute or replace function?

Tags: replace, syntax, pine-script

#### Background

I've built and published a script to retrieve daily short volume data via the Quandl data connector:

[Short Volume Script](https://www.tradingview.com/script/tKE3oaWC-Short-Interest-Shs-Outstanding-Short-Ratio-by-golesco/)

I actually just discovered that this script doesn't correctly access the data for preferred or classed shares like `BRK.A`, `BRK.B` because of the literal period in the symbol / ticker code which on Quandl I believe is either a slash or an underscore.

#### Code

This is what I've currently used in my script so far:

```
quandl_ticker = "QUANDL:FINRA/FNSQ_" + syminfo.ticker
quandl_dly_sh_vol = security(quandl_ticker, "D", close )
```

What I'm looking for would be something to the effect of:

```
"QUANDL:FINRA/FNSQ_" + substitute( syminfo.ticker, ".", "_" )
```

Which transforms the `BRK.B` into `BRK_B`. I hope that's clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `str.replace_all` built-in function sounds like what you are looking for:

```
quandl_ticker = "QUANDL:FINRA/FNSQ_" + str.replace_all(syminfo.ticker, ".", "_")
```